# Storybook - Vue components written .js format, not .vue format

Tags: vue.js, storybook

Is it possible to use vue components written in .js format as compared to .vue format with Storybook?

for example:

```js
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
data: function () {
return {
count: 0
}
},
template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
```

which might be called button-counter.js and imported into an index.html file with a script tag?